# Calculate time difference with time zone

Tags: php, datetime

I have a PHP page and a database in which I know the following:

- server time (server running PHP & DB)
- user time zone
- date/time of an event stored in DB

My system allows users to cancel an event (stamped with a certain time), and I need to figure out whether the event is within 12 hours of the user's time based on their current time zone. For example, suppose I have the following:

- server time (GMT): 7/1/2017 @ 3:30 PM
- user time zone: (GMT -7:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada)
- date/time of event: 7/1/2017 @ 8:30 PM (Mountain Time)

What would be the PHP formula to calculate the hours between user's current time and event time based on their known time zone? Note: We have many users in different time zones BUT we know their time zones because we store it in each user's database record. In order to solve the problem, we first need to calculate the user's current time by doing the math with server time and their time zone. Then we need to do a subtraction between their current time and the event time.

The time zone values I am storing are decimals in this format: `-7.0` (That is Mountain time, 7 hours later than GMT.) Whatever time zone calculation occurs needs to be able to take a decimal like that.

What is the PHP code to do this?

Comment: On StackOverflow you are expected to write your own code, we'll happily help you fix it if something isn't working, but you are expected to research and write the majority of it yourself.

Comment: Check out [IntlCalendar](http://php.net/manual/en/class.intlcalendar.php), and use it if you can!

Answer (score 0):

Use the diff() method of PHP's DateTime class like this:-

```
$user_time= new DateTime('.....',new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
$event_time= new DateTime('....',new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
var_dump($event_time->diff($user_time));
```

This will give you a DateInterval object:-

```
object(DateInterval)[48]
  public 'y' => int 0
  public 'm' => int 0
  public 'd' => int 2
  public 'h' => int 11
  public 'i' => int 34
  public 's' => int 41
  public 'invert' => int 0
  public 'days' => int 2
```

Retrieving the values you want from that is trivial.

Comment: Omis this looks promising, but time zone has to factor into the equation in order to get correct $user_time. How is that done?

Comment: I will edit my answer so that you can see the change including time zone

Comment: I get nothing but blanks: `$user_time= new DateTime('2017-05-22 13:48:20',new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
$event_time= new DateTime('2017-05-22 02:48:20');
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($event_time->diff($user_time));
echo "</pre>";`

Comment: The time zone values I am storing are decimals in this format: `-7.0` (That is Mountain time, 7 hours later than GMT.) Whatever time zone calculation occurs needs to be able to take a decimal like that.